Records lost in object type conversion
System.debug('#!inside cachechk'+Cache.getRecords('Selling_Price__c', criteriaMap).size());
for (SObject o: Cache.getRecords('Selling_Price__c', criteriaMap))
{
    Selling_Price__c SP = (Selling_Price__c)o;
    ProductsSellingPrices.put(SP.Product__c, SP.Selling_Price_ex_GST__c);
}
System.debug('@@@ Product Selling Price' +ProductsSellingPrices.keySet().size());

this code fetches the selling price records for each product. The first line return me 54 records but the last line output is 4. I'm so confused here

Most likely the value of Product__c isn't unique, therefore on each ProductsSellingPrices.put(key, value) you're overwrinting the previous value. If the value is the same for each product, you don't have to worry about it, while if the value may be different for the same product, you should either use a map of list (i.e. assuming that Selling_Price_ex_GST__c is a numeric field, the right map is Map<String, List<Decimal>>) or a composite key to uniquely identify a product
